# ShippingRates not getting in Shopify SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, shopify

I am working on shopify SDK in iOS app.

I want to get shipping rates. when I call this method:

```
- (NSOperation *)getShippingRatesForCheckoutWithToken:(NSString *)checkoutToken completion:(BUYDataShippingRatesBlock)block
{
    BUYAssertToken(checkoutToken);

    NSURL *url  = [self urlForCheckoutsShippingRatesWithToken:checkoutToken parameters:@{
                                                                                          @"checkout" : @"",
                                                                                          }];

    BUYRequestOperation *operation = (BUYRequestOperation *)[self getRequestForURL:url start:NO completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *json, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSArray *shippingRates = nil;
        if (json && !error) {
            shippingRates = [self.modelManager insertShippingRatesWithJSONArray:json[@"shipping_rates"]];
        }

        block(shippingRates, [self statusForStatusCode:response.statusCode error:error], error);
    }];

    operation.pollingHandler = ^BOOL(NSDictionary *json, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        return response.statusCode == BUYStatusProcessing;
    };

    [self startOperation:operation];
    return operation;
}
```

Then, response is like:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000004266c0> 
{ URL: https://3abbas.myshopify.com/api/checkouts/4f9d202e6998631042d9a519c6b05cc3/shipping_rates.json?checkout= } { status code: 412, headers }
```

and:

```
Error Domain=BUYShopifyErrorDomain Code=412 "(null)" UserInfo={errors={
    checkout =     {
        "shipping_address" =         (
                        {
                code = blank;
                message = "can't be blank";
                options =                 {
                };
            }
        );
    };
}}
```

How can I get the shipping rates? Can I pass static shipping rates in checkout?

Comment: What's the reason for minus point please put comment here

Comment: You will get shipping rates only based on the address. I have kept the static address and tried to get the shipping rates by the same way as you are doing. and getting no rates no errors.